# Using jquery migrate for plugins incompatible with jquery 1.10.2

Tags: plugins, jquery

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin that is not compatable with jquery 1.10.2 in Wordpress 3.6 and was able to fix it by using jquery migrate which apparently also ships with 3.6.

I thought I could perhaps include it as a dependency like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tf_load_custom_scripts');

function tf_load_custom_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('curtain', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/curtain.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-migrate'), 2.0 ); 
    wp_register_script('curtain-instance', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/curtain-instance.min.js', array('curtain','jquery','jquery-migrate'), true ); 

    if( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('curtain');
        wp_enqueue_script('curtain-instance');
    }


    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/script.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true );

}
```

but it still isn't working so I would love some help.

Comment: What *specifically* isn't working? Is the `jquery-migrate` script not getting enqueued, or is your Plugin not working as intended, even with `jquery-migrate` enqueued.

Comment: When I look in the web dev tools jquery-migrate is listed along with jquery in wp-includes but this was true before I added it as a dependancy. When I use jquery 1.10.2 in my html mockup the plugin breaks but when I include jquery-migrate it works again so I am guessing that it is perhaps not loading in the right order?

Comment: When you look at a rendered page: has a link for `jquery-migrate` been added? If so, then is it output *before* or *after* the `jquery` link?

Comment: before. Also although I included the `$in_footer` parameter as true my script is still loading in the head. I have `wp_footer()`in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `wp_register_script()` call:

```
wp_register_script('curtain-instance', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/curtain-instance.min.js', array('curtain','jquery','jquery-migrate'), true );
```

You're missing the `version` parameter:

```
wp_register_script(
    // Handle
    'curtain-instance', 
    // Path
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/curtain-instance.min.js', 
    // Dependencies
    array('curtain','jquery','jquery-migrate'), 
    // Version
    // In footer?
    true 
);
```

Try adding that parameter:

```
wp_register_script(
    // Handle
    'curtain-instance', 
    // Path
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/curtain-instance.min.js', 
    // Dependencies
    array('curtain','jquery','jquery-migrate'), 
    // Version
    '1.0',
    // In footer?
    true 
);
```

Two other things:

1. Be careful about *stylesheet* directory vs *template* directory. Unless you're working with a **Child Theme**, you need to use `get_template_directory_uri()` rather than `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.
2. You can simplify things by chaining your dependencies, and then only enqueueing the last in the chain:

   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tf_load_custom_scripts');

   function tf_load_custom_scripts() {

   ```
   wp_register_script( 'curtain', 
       get_template_directory_uri().'/curtain.min.js', 
       array( 'jquery', 'jquery-migrate' ), 
       2.0 
   ); 
   wp_register_script(
       'curtain-instance', 
       get_template_directory_uri().'/curtain-instance.min.js', 
       array( 'curtain' ), 
       '1.0',
       true 
   ); 

   if ( is_front_page() ) {
       wp_enqueue_script('curtain-instance');
   }


   wp_enqueue_script(
       'custom_script', 
       get_template_directory_uri().'/script.min.js', 
       array( 'jquery' ), 
       1.0, 
       true 
   );
   ```

   }

And finally, note that when WordPress registers jQuery, [it **defines `jquery-migrate` as a dependency**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L136):

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.10.2' );
```

So, try removing the `jquery-migrate` dependency:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tf_load_custom_scripts');

function tf_load_custom_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'curtain', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/curtain.min.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        2.0 
    ); 
    wp_register_script(
        'curtain-instance', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/curtain-instance.min.js', 
        array( 'curtain' ), 
        '1.0',
        true 
    ); 

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('curtain-instance');
    }


    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_script', 
        get_template_directory_uri().'/script.min.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        1.0, 
        true 
    );

}
```

Comment: Definitely better. The scripts are now loading in the right places. I now have an error which might explain why its not working : `http://localhost:8888/trouble_focusing/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found) :8888/trouble_focusing/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map:1` I found the answer for fixing this : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-wp-adminjquery-1102minmap-404-not-found?replies=19 but apparently that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Ended up using another script (parallax.js) and it works fine. I guess the problem was with curtains. Perhaps there was a js conflict. Thanks so much for your help. I decided to mark it as correct as it worked with the other script.